# Errors updating zesty packages - apt update/upgrade

Tags: updates, 17.04

I am trying to update zesty and facing errors. I tried apt-get update/upgrade and apt update as well. I can see that updates are available though. I tried through update manager GUI but faced an issue.

```
Ign:9 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                       
Ign:11 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
Ign:12 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
Ign:13 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
Err:14 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty Release
  404  Not Found
Err:15 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release
  404  Not Found
Err:16 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release
  404  Not Found
Err:17 http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release
  404  Not Found
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.adminbannok.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I'm seeing the `The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release' is no longer signed.` error too.  The file `Release.gpg ` appears to be missing from that site.

Comment: Has anyone faced this similar issue? I am really stuck with this. I tried reinstall in terminal. Still no success

Comment: I'am faced with same problem. I guess that the problem is in the mirrors. Someone has removed 17.04 from them. Despite other intermediate releases for example 17.10, 16.10. Perhaps this was done by mistake. Time will tell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in release [notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes). Zesty will be supported for 9 months until January 2018. Therefore you can use `old-releases` site, to install zesty packages.

You can use following sources list entries:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

# this repo is disabled!
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

It can be successfully retrieved by apt without any problems.

Comment: TIL to always install LTS releases

Comment: Which file should this lines be written into?

Answer (score -2):

I am to faced same problem with my system.
What I found is at url http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

========================================================

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[DIR]   Parent Directory        -
[DIR]   devel/  25-Jul-2017 12:18   -
[DIR]   hardy/  21-Oct-2011 17:54   -
[DIR]   lucid/  28-Oct-2015 15:29   -
[DIR]   maverick/   21-Oct-2011 16:34   -
[DIR]   natty/  08-Jul-2011 18:43   -
[DIR]   oneiric/    20-Oct-2011 00:08   -
[DIR]   precise/    25-Jul-2017 12:18   -
[DIR]   quantal/    04-Sep-2012 15:39   -
[DIR]   trusty/ 27-Jul-2017 07:45   -
[DIR]   vivid/  15-Apr-2015 20:46   -
[DIR]   wily/   21-Oct-2015 22:03   -
[DIR]   xenial/ 25-Jul-2017 12:18   -

=======================================================

**The zesty is missing.  ^**

I changed my zesty with xenial as below and it worked fine for me :

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial main

Comment: Adding pkgs from another release can brake you system. Users should install LTS releases instead of testing.