# Issues Installing PHP-intl Linux (404 Error)

Tags: apt, php

I am trying to run OwnCloud on my Linux server and I need to have PHP-INTL installed. I've looked into installing it via the command line with either

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

When I try to install it using these commands I get an error stating:

```
"Err:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-intl amd64 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]"
```

Which is then followed by a second error which just states that Linux was unable to fetch the package.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-intl_7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]    

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Can anyone give me some advice as to why my installation is doing this?

Comment: Ubuntu Zesty (17.04) is a standard release of Ubuntu with a supported life of 9 months.  It was released in 2017.April (hence 17.04 as releases are yy.mm format) so EOL is easily calculated. You should have upgraded to 17.10 (which was the 17.04 upgrade path), with 17.10 now EOL too. If you're quick in upgrading, 17.10 repo's haven't moved to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` yet so `do-release-upgrade` will be easier (*until they are moved*), but that window closes soon. Stick to LTS or long-term-support releases if you want a longer 5 year supported life span (17.10 upgrades to 18.04 LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen on [this related answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951091/errors-updating-zesty-packages-apt-update-upgrade), Ubuntu Zeisty is no longer supported since January 2018.

The best path, to me, is upgrading to an LTS release which guarantees years of *supported* upgrades.

If you need to stay with Zeisty (or don't feel confident to do a release upgrade) the solution to the question linked was to use the `old-releases` repository.

[Here's the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) on how to enable upgrades for EOL releases.